# Why is my update in react redux creating a new data with the update i did instead just editing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I don't know why my update form is recreating a new data with the item I passed it to edit an already existing item and also, the component doesn't reload to show the new state. I have to refresh it to see the change but I see the change on my redux chrome inspector immediately I click Submit.

What I have done, I have used the useEffect hook to listen to when there's change on the editForm state.

The complete code is on my gitHub too, is a very simply code.

Here's the code

```
EditForm component

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {taskEdit} from '../action/taskAction'

function TaskEditForm(props) {

  const [task, setTask] = useState(props.task)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTask(props.task)
  }, [props])
  
  const handleChange = e => {
    setTask({
      ...task,
      name : e.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {name} = task

    const newTask = {
      name
    }

    props.taskEdit(task._id, newTask)
    props.isEditing(false)

  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text"  value={task.name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button>Edit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default connect(null, {taskEdit})(TaskEditForm)

Reducer

 case TASK_UPDATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks : state.tasks.map(task=>{
          if(task.id === action.payload.id){
            return Object.assign({}, task, {
              name : action.payload.task
            })
          } else {
            return task
          }
        })
      }


Action 

export const taskEdit = (id, task) => dispatch => {

  const req = {
    method : "POST",
    headers : {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    body : JSON.stringify(task)
  }

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/task/add', req)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => dispatch({
    type : TASK_UPDATE,
    payload : {
      id,
      task
    }
  }))

}
```

The complete code is on my gitHub too, is a very simply code.

Comment: This is how updates in React work in general, you return a new object reference versus just mutating the existing one so the component rerenders. You likely need to refresh to see the updated data because the `TaskEditForm` only gets `taskEdit` from redux. Is there *some* parent component subscribed to the store that is passing in an updated props object with the updated `task` prop value?

Comment: Yes, i'm passed the data from the taskDetail component because I don't know how to pass a single item to the edit component.

Comment: Do you mind updating your question to include the parent component code so we may see how the `task` value is maintained and passed as prop?

Comment: Saw a flaw. `name : action.payload.task` should be `name: action.payload.task.name`. Right?

Comment: And I think it can be better if you specific what are exactly included in props. Like `function TaskEditForm({task, isEditing, ...}) {`

`[props]` in the useEffect can be replaced with `[props.task]`.